# Goldengate get an unique constraint error during insert into a simple table

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate

I have a two node gg1 and gg2 setup of goldengate. Seem to work. However when I insert a row into my table T1

```
connect sender/oracle
create table t1 (f1 char, f2 char);
alter table t1 add constraint t1_i1 primary key (f1);
```

I get an error

2022-01-30T19:16:05.705-0500  WARNING OGG-01154  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery for Oracle, d_rep.prm:  SQL error 1 mapping SENDER.T1 to SENDER.T1 OCI Error ORA-00001: unique constraint (SENDER.T1_I1) violated (status = 1), SQL <INSERT INTO "SENDER"."T1" ("F1","F2") VALUES (:a0,:a1)>.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pm11.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzozB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP6Ue.png)

here are prm files for gg1

```
# cat s_ext.prm
extract s_ext
userid ggs_owner, password Newpassword_2
tranlogoptions excludeuser ggs_owner
exttrail /u01/gg/dirdat/lt
ddl include all
getupdatebefores
sequence sender.*;
table sender.*;

# cat s_pmp.prm
extract s_pmp
userid ggs_owner, password Newpassword_2
rmthost 10.10.0.216, mgrport 7809
rmttrail /u01/gg/dirdat/rt
passthru
sequence sender.*;
table sender.*;

# cat d_rep.prm
replicat d_rep
userid ggs_owner, password Newpassword_2
assumetargetdefs
discardfile /u01/gg/dirrpt/drep1.dsc, append
reperror (default, exception)
map sender.*, target sender.*;
MACRO #exception_handler
 BEGIN
 , TARGET GGS_OWNER.GGS_EXCEPTIONS
 , COLMAP ( rep_name = @GETENV('GGENVIRONMENT', 'GROUPNAME')
 , TABLE_NAME = @GETENV ('GGHEADER', 'TABLENAME')
 , ERRNO = @GETENV ('LASTERR', 'DBERRNUM')
 , DBERRMSG = @GETENV ('LASTERR', 'DBERRMSG')
 , OPTYPE = @GETENV ('LASTERR', 'OPTYPE')
 , ERRTYPE = @GETENV ('LASTERR', 'ERRTYPE')
 , LOGRBA = @GETENV ('GGHEADER', 'LOGRBA')
 , LOGPOSITION = @GETENV ('GGHEADER', 'LOGPOSITION')
 , COMMITTIMESTAMP = @GETENV ('GGHEADER', 'COMMITTIMESTAMP')
 , GGS_FILENAME = @GETENV('GGFILEHEADER', 'FILENAME')
 , CDRFAIL = @GETENV('DELTASTATS','CDR_RESOLUTIONS_FAILED')
 , CDRSUC = @GETENV('DELTASTATS','CDR_RESOLUTIONS_SUCCEEDED')
 , CDRDETECT = @GETENV('DELTASTATS','CDR_CONFLICTS'))
 , INSERTALLRECORDS
 , EXCEPTIONSONLY;
 END;
MAP sender.* #exception_handler();
```

site gg2 is similar.

All row that i insert get insert with no abends but the warning confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the message you are getting a Key violation. Does the target table already have a record with the same key?  Your exceptions mapping is handling it and you should see records in the ggs.ggs_exceptions table.  Also, do a STATS on Replicat.

STATS REPLICAT repname TOTAL

and look for discards or collisions.

Answer (score 0):

It seem like key "1" might already be on the target database.  can you check that first?

ALso, you might want to remove the reperror and exception to test.